# User friendly php try catch

Tags: php, try-catch

Since a short period of time I'm working with Try Catch in PHP.  Now, every time a new error is thrown you get a fatal error on the screen, this isn't really user friendly so I was wondering if there's a way to give the user a nice message like an echo instead of a fatal error.

This is the code I have now:

```
public static function forceNumber($int){
    if(is_numeric($int)){
        return $int;
} else {
        throw new TypeEnforcerException($int.' must be a number');
}
}

public function setStatus($status) {
    try {
        $this->status = TypeEnforcer::forceInt($status); 
    } catch (TypeEnforcerException $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Well if there was no way to do that then there would be no point of a try-catch block. That is what it actually does

Comment: Could you might explain how then...?

Comment: Yea, share some code you already tried

Comment: But if you have syntax errors generating fatal errors then its not about exception handling. Its that your code won't even execute. So those need to be still fixed first, yes you can disable error display on screen and log it in the background

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean. The use of try catch is that the try stops beiing excecuted once it fails so the user must see what he's doing wrong, for example a status may only contain a number, if they fill in a string it must be told.

Comment: Do you mean [exception handling](http://php.net/set_exception_handler) ?

Comment: What i want to reach is: lets say.. if($name >= 10) { echo: name is to long; } but then with a try block, that try's the code and if there's something wrong the user must get an echo with a message what is wrong, but i thought this idea was possible through try catch with throw new exception. Im really bad at explaning sorry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is best solved with a frontend controller that is able to catch all uncatched exceptions:

```
<?php
require('bootstrap.php');

try {
    $controllerService->execute($request);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $controllerService->handleControllerException($e);
}
```

You can then write code to return the internal server error because an exception signals an exceptional case so it normally is an 500 internal server error. The user must not be interested what went wrong other than it just didn't work out and your program crashed.

If you throw exceptions to give validation notices you need to catch those in a different layer (and you're probably doing it wrong if you use exceptions for that).

---

*Edit:* For low-level functions, because PHP is loosely typed, if a function expects and int, [cast to int<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling#language.types.typecasting):

```
public static function forceNumber($int){
    $int = (int) $int;
    return $int;
}
```

this will actually force the integer. In case the cast is not possible to do (e.g. `$int` it totally incompatible) PHP will throw the exception for you.

The example is a bit akward because by the method's name you use it to validate some number and provide an error if not (here wrongly with an exception). Instead you should do some validation. If you expect wrong input, it's not an exceptional case when wrong input is provided, so I would not use exceptions for that.

Comment: I wanted to use exceptions also for normal error messages to the user yes. They must know what they are doing wrong, if i have a name field and they fill it in too long, short etc then they must get a message, name is to short/long. I thought it was possible to use exceptions for that aswell.

Comment: @NickAudenaerde: That is not an exception. That is a message some validation layer returns so that you can put the messages into the output. That normally is done in some request/form validation layer. In lower-level functions you then throw "real" exceptions (if necessary). Keep in mind that one request can have *multiple* error messages, but there is only one exception.

Comment: @NickAudenaerde I'm not sure that's the reason exceptions are designed for.

Comment: @NickAudenaerde: I also updated the answer to show you casting which is something I normally use in the low-level function in PHP.

Comment: @hakre, doesn't your model fail when the first line throws an exception?

Comment: You mean the `Class::forceNumber()` method? Or requiring the bootstrap? (and how would that be an issue?/what are you concerned about?)